# LiveFilter in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'v got a question about LiveFilter. Or how to make it in another way without LiveFilter it is not so important. So iv got the page and got divs which are making from JSON file. And my filter is not working. So i got my page like this [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSFoZ.png) And when im start searching by the name or number it should be like this [AfterShouldBe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcaqO.png)
So im using jquery.livefilter.js

```
    <script> // Reading DATA from JSON
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("accounts.json", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $("#main_list").append(
                        buildRow(value.name
                                ,value.number
                                ,value.city,value.amount,value.currency,value.rate)
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#livefilter-list').liveFilter('#livefilter-input', 'li', {
            filterChildSelector: 'a'
        });
    });
</script>
<script> // Making divs from JSON
    function buildRow(a,b,c,d,e,f){
        return '<ul id="livefilter-list"><div class="deposit-small-block first-block size-small-block tt" onclick="view(\'t1\'); return false">\
    <div class="button_block">\
        <div class="div-for-button">\
            <input type="radio" name="on">\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="deposit-form-block-name">\
        <div class="deposit-form-block-name-first white-text"><name><li>'+a+'</li></name></div>\
        <div class="deposit-form-block-name-second white-text"><number><li>'+b+'</li></number></div>\
        <div class="deposit-form-block-name-third white-text"><city>'+c+'</city></div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="deposit-form-block-sum">\
        <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text">\
            <amount>'+d+'</amount><br><currency>'+e+'</currency>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="deposit-form-block-perc">\
        <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text"><rate>'+f+'</rate></div>\
    </div>\
</div>\
</ul>'
    }
</script>
```

So could someone tell me where is the problem
And here is my rar with files (html, css, js, json)

Comment: Cant pick up more than 2 links, so here is the link with my files - [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ov-TJi--Z8TGl5bUI2cDhqd00/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about [liveFilter.js](http://cheeaun.github.io/jquery.livefilter/)...
Your HTML is too complex for it.

I made a pretty small script for you.... Customized for your web page.

**How it works:**
On the `input` event, hide all rows.

Then search the inputted value within `<name>`, `<number>` and `<city>` content... For each rows, using the JavaScript method `.indexOf()`.

If the search term is found, this row must be displayed.

```
// Custom search
$("#livefilter-input").on("input",function(){
    //console.log("Searching...");

    // Set ALL rows to display none.
    $(".deposit-small-block").css("display","none");

    // Loop to check the content of all custom tags: <name> <number> and <city>
    $(".tt").find(".deposit-form-block-name .white-text").children().each(function(){

        // If a matching text is found within name, account # or city
        if( $(this).html().indexOf( $("#livefilter-input").val() ) != -1 ){
            //console.log("FOUND a match!");

            // Set this row to display block.
            $(this).closest(".deposit-small-block").css("display","block");
        }
    });
});
```

Place it inside the document ready wrapper, just below the `$.getJSON` function.
[**Live link!**](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40269206/search.html)

**EDIT:**
For case insensitive search:

Only one line to change:

```
if( $(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf( $("#livefilter-input").val().toLowerCase() ) != -1 ){
```

Comment: Thank You very much again. So if i want to make it case-insensitive search, i just should add toLowerCase, am I right?

Comment: Right. On both elements in the comparison. I edited my answer.

Comment: Check the id of the search input... In this example, it is `livefilter-input`. But you should change it to something like `myCustomSearch`... Descriptive classes and ids are helpfull. ;)