# Change data in div by clicking on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Could some one help me with one question:

I have 2 divs.
The first one is made of DATA from JSON file.

I have a function that makes few rows (depending on how many DATA I have in JSON).
So by clicking on one row, it should show another div with additional info about this option.
If I click on another option it should update info.

It actually works like that:
I click on first option --> it shows the DIV.
I click on the 2nd option, it is closing the DIV.

I just made the function that change the CSS (display:none/block).

Here is the code of first DIV:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function view(n){
        style = document.getElementById(n).style;
        style.display = (style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
</script>
<script> // Reading DATA from JSON
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("accounts.json", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $("#main_list").append(
                        buildRow(value.name
                                ,value.number
                                ,value.city,value.amount,value.currency,value.rate)
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<script> // Making divs from JSON
    function buildRow(a,b,c,d,e,f){
        return '<div class="deposit-small-block first-block size-small-block tt" onclick="view(\'t1\'); return false">\
                    <div class="button_block">\
                        <div class="div-for-button">\
                            <input type="radio" name="on">\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="deposit-form-block-name">\
                        <div class="deposit-form-block-name-first white-text"><name>'+a+'</name></div>\
                        <div class="deposit-form-block-name-second white-text"><number>'+b+'</number></div>\
                        <div class="deposit-form-block-name-third white-text"><city>'+c+'</city></div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="deposit-form-block-sum">\
                        <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text">\
                            <amount>'+d+'</amount><br><currency>'+e+'</currency>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="deposit-form-block-perc">\
                        <div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text"><rate>'+f+'</rate></div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
                '
    }
</script>
```

And the code of 2nd DIV:

```
<aside id="t1" class="right-sidebar">
<div class="right-sidebar-header">
    <div class="right-sidebar-header-text">Информация о выбранном вкладе
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function openbox(id){
        display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

        if(display=='none'){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="box2">
    <div class="first-option">
        <div class="best-text"><a href="#"
                                 style="color: black"
                                 class="dot"
                                 onclick="openbox('box');
                                 return false">Условия</a>
        </div>

        <div id="box" style="display: none;">
            <div class="first-option-inside">
                <div class="first-option-inside-table-first grey-text">Ставка</div>
                <div class="first-option-inside-table-second grey-text">Дата открытия</div>
                <div class="first-option-inside-table-third grey-text">Дата окончания</div>
            </div>
            <div class="first-option-inside">
                <div class="first-option-inside-table-first-under">7.4%</div>
                <div class="first-option-inside-table-second-under">23.04.2015</div>
                <div class="first-option-inside-table-third-under">23.04.2017</div>
            </div>
            <div class="max-sum-text">Максимальная сумма</div>
            <div class="min-sum-text">1 000 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>
            <div class="max-sum-text">Неснижаемый остаток</div>
            <div class="min-sum-text">1 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>
            <div class="max-sum-text">Минимальная сумма пополнения наличными</div>
            <div class="min-sum-text">1 000 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>
            <div class="max-sum-text">Доступная сумма для снятия</div>
            <div class="min-sum-text">20 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

How it looks like:
[image: How it looks like]

Then I click on any of name, it opens div.
And when I click on another name, it should update my information (see where circled in black).
[image: here in the black rounds]
So should I add this info into my JSON?
Or how to realize this?

Thank you to your answers.

Comment: and here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ov-TJi--Z8dTFIbGJKM01UbFk/view?usp=sharing) with my files (json, html, css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to carry the `index` of the needed information within the `data` array.

So if you put this `index` in the `onclick="view(...)` of each row, you carry it to the `view()` function.
The `view()` function opens the right panel on click on a row...
So it's the best place to update the relevant infos to view.

**So here is the updated script:**

```
var jsonArray=[];
var lastIndexViewed=-1;

function view(n,index) {

    if( (lastIndexViewed==index) || (lastIndexViewed==-1) ){    // Improved the condition to take lask viewed in account.
        style = document.getElementById(n).style;
        style.display = (style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    console.log("jsonArray index "+index+" data is required."); // Index is present... Let's use it.

    // Place the info at the right places.
    $("#"+n).find("#rate").html(jsonArray[index].rate);
    $("#"+n).find("#open_date").html(jsonArray[index].open_date);
    $("#"+n).find("#close_date").html(jsonArray[index].close_date);
    $("#"+n).find("#max_sum").html(jsonArray[index].max_sum);
    $("#"+n).find("#min_balance").html(jsonArray[index].min_balance);
    $("#"+n).find("#min_sum_in").html(jsonArray[index].min_sum_in);
    $("#"+n).find("#sum_take").html(jsonArray[index].sum_take);

    // Keep last viewed index in memory to prevent boring div close when trying to view another row.
    lastIndexViewed=index;
}

// Reading DATA from JSON
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("accounts.json", function(data){

        // Saving the array to use it later
        console.log(data);
        jsonArray = data;

        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            $("#main_list").append(
                    buildRow(value.name,
                            value.number,
                            value.city,
                            value.amount,
                            value.currency,
                            value.rate,
                            key)            // To carry the index of the array of json objects.
            );
            console.log("On row buiding, the index within jsonArray: "+key);    // This is the index
        });
    });
});

// Making divs from JSON
function buildRow(a,b,c,d,e,f,index){
    return '<div class="deposit-small-block first-block size-small-block tt" onclick="view(\'t1\','+index+'); return false">'+  // The index is sent to the function that opens the right div.
                '<div class="button_block">'+
                    '<div class="div-for-button">'+
                        '<input type="radio" name="on">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="deposit-form-block-name">'+
                    '<div class="deposit-form-block-name-first white-text"><name>'+a+'</name></div>'+
                    '<div class="deposit-form-block-name-second white-text"><number>'+b+'</number></div>'+
                    '<div class="deposit-form-block-name-third white-text"><city>'+c+'</city></div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="deposit-form-block-sum">'+
                    '<div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text">'+
                        '<amount>'+d+'</amount><br><currency>'+e+'</currency>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="deposit-form-block-perc">'+
                    '<div class="deposit-form-block-sum-text white-text"><rate>'+f+'</rate></div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'
}
```

**The only HTML changed:**
I only added some ids to each `div` where information is expected.
I didn't remove the classes, which look useless(?).

```
<div id="box" style="display: none;">
    <div class="first-option-inside">
        <div class="first-option-inside-table-first grey-text">Ставка</div>
        <div class="first-option-inside-table-second grey-text">Дата открытия</div>
        <div class="first-option-inside-table-third grey-text">Дата окончания</div>
    </div>
    <div class="first-option-inside">
        <div id="rate" class="first-option-inside-table-first-under">7.4%</div>
        <div id="open_date" class="first-option-inside-table-second-under">23.04.2015</div>
        <div id="close_date" class="first-option-inside-table-third-under">23.04.2017</div>
    </div>
    <div class="max-sum-text">Максимальная сумма</div>
    <div id="max_sum" class="min-sum-text">1 000 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>
    <div class="max-sum-text">Неснижаемый остаток</div>
    <div id="min_balance" class="min-sum-text">1 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>
    <div class="max-sum-text">Минимальная сумма пополнения наличными</div>
    <div id="min_sum_in" class="min-sum-text">1 000 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>
    <div class="max-sum-text">Доступная сумма для снятия</div>
    <div id="sum_take" class="min-sum-text">20 000,00 Рубль РФ</div>

</div>
```

`id` should be used as a unique selector.
`class` should be used for collections.
I used the same `id` names as the property names in the json... For clarity.

**Have a look at the [live link](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/40269206/index.html) for this solution:**

*Side note:* Notice that I changed the order of your library loading:

```
<script src="jquery.livefilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.liveFilter.js"></script>
```

Because `liveFilter.js` needs jQuery to be loaded first.
I'm not even sure it is used...
In my solution, I commented it out and saw no effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and comment with detailed response. It is very useful for me to understand how it works.
Yes, i just used liveFilter to make search by NAME and NUMBERS, but it didnt work for me(so i deleted my function and forgot to delete script loading). I have tried to make another html with table and it worked(in table i mean), But when i used it on my divs, it didn't work.
Here is my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226400/livefilter-in-divs) If You know how to fix it, it will be nice to see the comments by your side. Thank you very much

Comment: I'll check your other question tomorrow. 3:15am here. ;)

Comment: No problem, sir :)